# Mutate a variable depending on several other variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this following dataframe

```
   ID FID Mother Father   Sib cousin Aunt uncle   PAT
1  A1   A                                       FALSE
2  A2   A                                       FALSE
3  A3   A     A1     A2    A4                   FALSE
4  A4   A     A1     A2    A3                    TRUE
5  B1   B                                       FALSE
6  B2   B                                       FALSE
7  B3   B     B1     B2 B4;B5     B8   B7    B6  TRUE
8  B4   B     B1     B2 B3;B5                   FALSE
9  B5   B               B3;B4                   FALSE
10 B6   B                                       FALSE
11 B7   B                                       FALSE
12 B8   B                         B3            FALSE
13 C1   C                                       FALSE
14 C2   C                                       FALSE
15 C3   C     C1     C2                          TRUE
```

I would like to add a column "family_relationship" that describes by FID, the familial relashionship between the ID that have TRUE in PAT and the other members as in the following output table.

```
   ID FID Mother Father   Sib cousin Aunt uncle   PAT family_relationship
1  A1   A                                       FALSE              Mother
2  A2   A                                       FALSE              Father
3  A3   A     A1     A2    A4                   FALSE                 Sib
4  A4   A     A1     A2    A3                    TRUE                 PAT
5  B1   B                                       FALSE              Mother
6  B2   B                                       FALSE              Father
7  B3   B     B1     B2 B4;B5     B8   B7    B6  TRUE                 PAT
8  B4   B     B1     B2 B3;B5                   FALSE                 Sib
9  B5   B               B3;B4                   FALSE                 sib
10 B6   B                                       FALSE               Uncle
11 B7   B                                       FALSE                Aunt
12 B8   B                         B3            FALSE              Cousin
13 C1   C                                       FALSE              Mother
14 C2   C                                       FALSE              Father
15 C3   C     C1     C2                          TRUE                 PAT
```

```
ID=c("A1","A2","A3","A4","B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "C1", "C2", "C3")
FID=c(rep("A",4), rep("B", 8), rep("C",3))
Mother=c("","","A1", "A1", "","","B1","B1","", "", "","","","","C1")
Father=c("","","A2", "A2", "","","B2","B2","", "", "","","","","C2")
Sib=c("","", "A4", "A3", "", "", "B4;B5","B3;B5", "B3;B4", "", "", "","", "", "" )
cousin=c("","","","","","","B8","","","","","B3", "","","")
Aunt=c("","","","","","","B7","","","","","", "","","")
uncle=c("","","","","","","B6","","","","","", "","","")
PAT=c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE" )
family_relationship=c("Mother", "Father", "Sib", "PAT", "Mother", "Father", "PAT", "Sib", "sib", "Uncle", "Aunt", "Cousin", "Mother", "Father", "PAT")
```

Comment: can you provide your dataframe using the output of dput(your_df) function? It's easier to reconstruct afterward.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to provide the values of the data. Is the way I provided them is ok ? Or is it better to use dput ?

Comment: in the last row, last column, it should PAT right? not PAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `tidyverse`.

First, create a look-up table of relationships where `PAT` is `TRUE`. Then, merge back with your data and join based on `FID` and `ID`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(PAT == TRUE) %>%
  select(-PAT, -ID) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -FID, names_to = "family_relationship", values_to = "ID") %>%
  separate_rows(ID, sep = ";") %>%
  right_join(df, by = c("FID", "ID")) %>%
  mutate(family_relationship = replace(family_relationship, 
                                       is.na(family_relationship) & PAT == T, 
                                       "PAT")) %>%
  arrange(FID, ID) %>%
  relocate(family_relationship, .after = PAT)
```

**Output**

```
   FID   ID    Mother Father Sib     Cousin Aunt  Uncle PAT   family_relationship
   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              
 1 A     A1    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Mother             
 2 A     A2    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Father             
 3 A     A3    "A1"   "A2"   "A4"    ""     ""    ""    FALSE Sib                
 4 A     A4    "A1"   "A2"   "A3"    ""     ""    ""    TRUE  PAT                
 5 B     B1    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Mother             
 6 B     B2    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Father             
 7 B     B3    "B1"   "B2"   "B4;B5" "B8"   "B7"  "B6"  TRUE  PAT                
 8 B     B4    "B1"   "B2"   "B3;B5" ""     ""    ""    FALSE Sib                
 9 B     B5    ""     ""     "B3;B4" ""     ""    ""    FALSE Sib                
10 B     B6    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Uncle              
11 B     B7    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Aunt               
12 B     B8    ""     ""     ""      "B3"   ""    ""    FALSE Cousin             
13 C     C1    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Mother             
14 C     C2    ""     ""     ""      ""     ""    ""    FALSE Father             
15 C     C3    "C1"   "C2"   ""      ""     ""    ""    TRUE  PAT
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a solution but your instruction are somehow tricky because for instance, B1 and B2 do not appear anywhere in the "family" columns. I therefore took the freedom to assign them `NA`

```
df = data.frame(ID,FID,Mother,Father,Sib,cousin,Aunt,uncle,PAT)
a = c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[i,"PAT"]== 'TRUE'){
      a=c(a,setNames('PAT',i))
    }
  if(df[i,"PAT"]== 'FALSE'){
    
      for(n in 2:ncol(df)){
        if(length(grep(df[i,"ID"],df[,n]))>0){
          
          a= c(a, setNames(colnames(df)[n],i)) 
        }
       
      }}
    }
  
df$family_relationship=NA
df[which(!1:nrow(df)%in%names(a)),"family_relationship"]=NA
df[as.numeric(names(a)),"family_relationship"]=as.character(a)
```

the result looks like this:

```
   ID FID Mother Father   Sib cousin Aunt uncle   PAT family_relationship
1  A1   A                                       FALSE              Mother
2  A2   A                                       FALSE              Father
3  A3   A     A1     A2    A4                   FALSE                 Sib
4  A4   A     A1     A2    A3                    TRUE                 PAT
5  B1   B                                       FALSE                <NA>
6  B2   B                                       FALSE                <NA>
7  B3   B     C1     C2 B4;B5     B8   B7    B6  TRUE                 PAT
8  B4   B     C1     C2 B3;B5                   FALSE                 Sib
9  B5   B               B3;B4                   FALSE                 Sib
10 B6   B                                       FALSE               uncle
11 B7   B                                       FALSE                Aunt
12 B8   B                         B3            FALSE              cousin
13 C1   C                                       FALSE              Mother
14 C2   C                                       FALSE              Father
15 C3   C     C1     C2                          TRUE                 PAT
```

Let me know if it's ok

Comment: So sorry for the remaining mistakes ("B1" and "B2" should have been in rows 7 and 8), and thank for suggesting me this solution that is working perfectly.